# Regex Match Replace

Tags: php, regex

Im trying to figure out a regex pattern that will look through array below and replace
any matching that has a '+' in it with emtpy/null, so if it has a positive number in it then make it null.

thanks for the help. Im still learning.

```
Array (
[0] => IND: -3
[1] => NYJ: +0
[2] => BAL: +3
[3] => CLE: +6
[4] => WSH: +5
[5] => DET: -2.5
[6] => ATL: +0
[7] => ARI: -7
[8] => OAK: +7
)

$pattern = '/(?<!A-Z\:)\+/i';
$replacement = '';
$replaced = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $line
```

Comment: You must enclose you character class inside square brackets and you have forgotten the space between ":" and the sign. However, the idea is good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting to `null` will unset it, so:

```
$array = preg_grep('/\+/', $array, PREG_GREP_INVERT);
```

Comment: nice! I always forget about `preg_grep` the unsung hero

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to go as far as regex for this problem; [`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos) will tell you if theres a `+` in the string. With that said, you can remove those occurences using [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/array_filter) like this:

```
$result = array_filter($array, function($i)
{
    return strpos($i, '+') === false;

});
```

Comment: Even though I posted a regex I normally always look for a non regex.

Answer (score 2):

```
array_walk($array, function(&$v){
  $v = (strpos($v,'+')!==false)? null : $v;
});
```

Comment: Even though I posted a regex I normally always look for a non regex.  Sup J!

Comment: @AbraCadaver shh don't tell people I hang out here, it would be scandalous! :P

Answer (score 1):

Regexes work on strings, not arrays. Looping through the array, performing integer comparison and reassigning the value back would probably be quicker and simpler.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Oh god you're right. I came here from the regex category. **Why would PHP do that?**

Comment: I don't know! I like so much write foreach loops.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution you could use.

```
foreach ($array as $k => $v) {
   if (preg_match('/\+/', $v)) {
     unset($array[$k]);
   }
}
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => IND: -3
    [5] => DET: -2.5
    [7] => ARI: -7
)
```

See [`working demo`](https://eval.in/68377)

Comment: This also worked fore me, but i chose the other one.. thank you

Answer (score 0):

For extra credit, how would i go about stripping the team names followed by '+'.
 the array looks like this.

```
 Array
(
[0] => IND: -3
TEN: +3
[1] => NYJ: -1
BUF: +1
[2] => BAL: +3
CHI: -3
[3] => CLE: +6
CIN: -6
[4] => WSH: +4.5
PHI: -4.5
[5] => DET: -2.5
PIT: +2.5
[6] => ATL: +1
TB: -1
[7] => ARI: -8.5
JAX: +8.5
[8] => OAK: +9
HOU: -9
[9] => SD: -1.5
MIA: +1.5
[10] => SF: +3
NO: -3
[11] => GB: +4.5
)
```

Comment: Ask as a separate question.